# How to fully span right-hand div, when left div is fixed size?

Tags: html, css

I'm having two `div` layouted as `inline-block`. I want the left div to be of a fixed size and the right to fully span of what is left on the line - but never move to the next line. So, to divs on the same line. One is fixed, the other fully spans.

I prepared a JSFiddle, which is NOT what I intended, because the divs are on seperate lines. 
Any CSS-expert that did this before?
http://jsfiddle.net/yT5Gc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">
        div 1
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container { width: 100%; }
#div1 { width: 200px; float: left; border:1px solid; }
#div2 { border:1px solid; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/WpJ4S/)

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS would do:

```
#left {width:80px; float: left;background-color: yellow;}
#right {background-color: red;}
```

I used a background-color to show which is which div. You'd have to use floats instead of inline-block though.

I have modified the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/yT5Gc/3/

Comment: I noticed, that the text wraps underneath the first div. How would you prevent that? display: table? Here the fiddle, which shows the deficiency. http://jsfiddle.net/yT5Gc/5/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the complete script. Flashback: I actually wanted 2 columns written with DIVs.

The trick is to set the overflow attribute to hidden:

```
div {border: 1px solid red;}
#left {width: 120px; float: left;}
#right {width: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yT5Gc/7/